# Pointers Showing Up in Response to lapply/map/for loops in R on AWS

Tags: r, amazon-web-services, pointers, amazon-ec2, rvest

I'm using the `rvest` package to loop through URLs and scrape some content. Below is a sample of my code.

```
library(magrittr)
library(rvest)

bb <- function(team) {
Sys.sleep(runif(1,2,7.75))
p1 <- try(read_html(paste0("http://www.basketball-reference.com/teams/",team,"/2017.html")))

c1 <- p1 %>% try(html_nodes("p")) %>% try(extract2(1)) %>% try(html_text(trim=TRUE))
c2 <- p1 %>% try(html_nodes("p")) %>% try(extract2(2)) %>% try(html_text(trim=TRUE))

tt <- cbind(team,c1,c2)
return(tt)
}

teams <- c('BOS','CLE','GSW','HOU')

x1 <- lapply(teams,bb)
```

When I run this code locally on my laptop, it's all good. When I put it on AWS, I get output that contains references to pointers. It looks like this:

node
BOS
< pointer: 0x6e42f430 >
< pointer: 0x6e42f430 >
doc
BOS
< pointer: 0x19099140 >
< pointer: 0x19099140 >
node
CLE
< pointer: 0x6a149730 >
< pointer: 0x6a149730 >
doc
CLE
< pointer: 0x6a0a6900 >
< pointer: 0x6a0a6900 >
node
GSW
< pointer: 0x1eed3e40 >
< pointer: 0x1eed3e40 >
doc
GSW
< pointer: 0x1e4fdc10 >
< pointer: 0x1e4fdc10 >
node
HOU
< pointer: 0x6a14d6e0 >
< pointer: 0x6a14d6e0 >
doc
HOU
< pointer: 0x6ca16c00 >
< pointer: 0x6ca16c00 >

I get the same result if I try `map` or a `for` loop. I'm assuming this is something with how my AWS EC2 instance is setup? I'm using this AMI: http://www.louisaslett.com/RStudio_AMI/

Any idea how I can get regular values instead of these pointers?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm still not sure entirely what's going on here, but I found something that worked locally and on AWS using the AMI noted above. basically you need to incorporate multiple try functions and *place them around the interim variables used within the function*, like so:

```
bb <- function(team) {
Sys.sleep(runif(1,2,7.75))
try(p1 <- read_html(paste0("http://www.basketball-reference.com/teams/",team,"/2017.html")))
try(c1 <- p1 %>% html_nodes("p") %>% html_text(trim=TRUE))
try(c2 <- p1 %>% html_nodes("p")) %>% html_text(trim=TRUE))

try(tt <- cbind(team,c1,c2))
return(tt)
}
```

so no idea what happened, but that solution worked for me. :)